# Using Element Properties with ArcGIS Report Designer?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, reports, attribute-index, streets

I've finally got a table generated that will work for a street index and I'm attempting to use the ‘Create Report’ tool with ArcGIS 10.1 to generate what I need for a map. Essentially, I have it setup and working but the gap that is generated between each street name is to large. I've been playing around with the ‘Element Properties’ and realized that the 'Can Grow' behavior is where my problem may lie. If I set this to 'True' the street names longer then the space available will be given more space horizontally. A nice ability to have but by having this setup it seems to cause every other street name to take up more space horizontally. If I switch the ‘Can Grow’ to ‘False’ it fixes the issue but doesn’t allow longer street names enough space. 
This is a problem because I have limited space on my map.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Should I be using excel and if so is there documentation on the process?

Am I missing something in the ‘Element Properties’?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your street index looks great, but I've not used View|Reports>Create Report enough to provide any advice on solving your problem.  If you hit a brickwall, then ArcPy with [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/) (Open Source) is likely to be able to provide an alternative solution but its syntax takes some working with.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks for the reference to ReportLab.  I'm really hoping I can get Reports within ArcGIS to work for me though.  I'll re-post once I have a solution.